# Update values by removing elements in the array with NodeJs and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The functionality I want to achieve:
On the frontend I have the list of all the owners in with checkboxes.. The added owners are already checked.. How can I achive that if I uncheck some owner ID and check like 2 new owners, so I remove the unchecked owner and add the new "checked" one.

I have a user model:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, min: 6, max: 255 },
  password: { type: String, required: true, min: 4, max: 1024 },
  role: { type: String, required: true, default: "User" },
  owners: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Owners",
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});
```

Every usser has an array of owners [image]

I add owner to the specific user with this query PUT METHOD:

```
exports.addOwnerToUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    let ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const user = {
      email: req.body.email,
      ownerId: req.body.ownerId,
    };

        const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.userId, owners: { $ne: req.body.ownerId } },
  { $push: { owners: { $each: req.body.ownerId } } },
  { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
);

    res.status(201).json({ sucess: true, msg: "User updated sucessfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json(err);
  }
};
```

**2.)** How can I achive that, if I on the frontend UNCHECK the owner, that it gets removed from owners array?

Comment: Could you adjust your title to be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: Uhhh, sorry didn't even realise about my title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like that:

```
exports.addOwnerToUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    let ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const user = {
      email: req.body.email,
      ownerId: req.body.ownerId,
    };

    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.userId },
      { $set: { owners: req.body.ownerId } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ owners: { $eq: user.ownerId } }], multi: true }
    );

    res.status(201).json({ sucess: true, msg: "User updated sucessfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: How does it work for both operations in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$pullAll`

This operation removes all instances of the values you set from the scores array

```
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.userId, owners: { $ne: req.body.ownerId } },
  { $pullAll: { owners: ["630367b3c8e06afa0339a609"] } },
);
```

You can read the docs [HERE](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/)

Comment: I can't make it work sadly :S

Answer (score 0):

Both the operations `$push` and `$pull` are not possible in single property in the update query it will generate a conflict error,

There are 3 options I would suggest,

1. If `owners` array has limited to a max of 10 elements then Get the whole array of owners id from the front-end and update that array, so don't require the push and pull operations
2. Execute 2 separate queries, first for push and the second for pull elements
3. try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) query starting from MongoDB 4.2, let's understand in an example:

Consider a document:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    owners: [
      ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
    ]
  }
]
```

Consider input variables:

```
let _id = "5a934e000102030405000000";
let addOwners = ["5a934e000102030405000001", "5a934e000102030405000002"];
let removeOwners = ["5a934e000102030405000000"];
```

Let's prepare our query,

- wrap the update part in an array bracket
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `owners` array nad remove provided id in `removeOwners` array variable
- `$concatArrays` to concat above filtered array after removing the ids, and add `addOwners` array variable

```
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: _id },
  [{
    $set: {
      owners: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$owners",
              cond: { $not: { $in: ["$$this", removeOwners] } }
            }
          },
          addOwners
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  { new: true }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i37MyYboc99)